# moderncv: How to automatically span the \cvitem entry over the remaining page width and indent it over multiple lines?

Tags: indentation, moderncv

I would like to replace the manual column width approach (i.e. `0.9\textwidth`) with an automatic way of determining the remaining `\textwidth` after subtracting the width of `\cvitem{Title}` from `\textwidth`. Additionally, I need to indent the text over multiple lines as shown in this output.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans,fullrules]{moderncv}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{Diaa}{Abidou}
\begin{document}


    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \smallskip
    \subsection{Philosophy of Doctor}
    \cventry{date}{Ph.D.}{University}{city}{}{}

    \cvitem{Title}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.9\textwidth}@{}}
            some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title
        \end{tabular}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `banking` style the command `\cvitem` is defined as

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{#3}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

For example can you define a new command `\mycvitem` with `tabularx`:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l{1ex}X}
    \hintstyle{#2}: & & #3%
  \end{tabularx}
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Please see that this command does not check if argument `#2` is empty or not. It is taken to be not empty now!

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[%
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  sans,
  fullrules
]{moderncv}

\usepackage[%
% tuenc
]{fontspec}


\usepackage{tabularx} % <===============================================
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{% <===================================
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lp{1ex}X}
    \hintstyle{#2}: & & #3%
  \end{tabularx}
  \par\addvspace{#1}} % <===============================================

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{Diaa}{Abidou}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
    \smallskip
    \subsection{Philosophy of Doctor}
    \cventry{date}{Ph.D.}{University}{city}{}{}

\cvitem{Title}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.9\textwidth}@{}}
            some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title
        \end{tabular}
}
\mycvitem{Title}{%
  some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title
}
\mycvitem{longTitle}{%
  some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title
}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]